# Datanucleus - Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell

Tags: java, excel, datanucleus

I'd like to use DataNucleus to read, and write .xls files. I've found a lot of this question with Apache POI, but if it's not necessary, I do not want to use Apache POI directly, instead of DataNucleus.

So, I have a test class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JUSTSTRING")
public class JustStringEntity {

    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

And some method, to write it to .xls, and read it from there.

```
public void exportSomeToXls(){
    JustStringEntity e1 = new JustStringEntity(); e1.setId(1); e1.setName("Mr. Salieri");
    JustStringEntity e2 = new JustStringEntity(); e2.setId(2); e2.setName("Thomas Angelo");

    EntityTransaction tx = xlsManager.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    xlsManager.persist(e1);
    xlsManager.persist(e2);
    tx.commit();
}

public void getSomeFromXls(){
    try {
        List<JustStringEntity> entities = xlsManager.createQuery("SELECT j from JustStringEntity j", JustStringEntity.class).getResultList();

        System.out.println("SIZE: " + entities.size());

        for (JustStringEntity j : entities) {
            System.out.println(j.getId());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It writes succesfully the data into the .xls file. But when I try to read it, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.typeMismatch(HSSFCell.java:637)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.getRichStringCellValue(HSSFCell.java:714)
    ....
```

If the `JustStringEntity` containt only `String` attributes, it works fine. But if it contains any numeric data, it fails.

Is there any simple method, to resolve this problem (without using directly Apache POI)?

Comment: I use spreadsheets fine with numeric values (floating point or integral). Is it only when the PK field is numeric? i.e have you tried String PK and numeric non-PK ? Also have you tried with a long primitive rather than Long wrapper?

Comment: With the primitive types, it works. Thanks, and if you post it as an answer, I'm gonna accept this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the `Long`/`Integer` changed to `long`/`int` (primitive).

I'd still expect it to work with primitive wrapper though, but maybe there was/is some bug for that particular case?

Comment: If the `@Id` is a wrapper class over a primitive type, it fails. If the `@Id` is a String, or a primitive type, it works. If other fields are wrapper classes, it works also.